# Matching dot at the beginning of a string using matches?

Tags: java, regex, matching

I'm trying to match a string, starting with a dot using java's matches method. Why this doesn't work:

```
".why?".matches("\\.*");
```

When I use a single slash, i'm getting an error for invalid escape sequence.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"\\.*"` matches a string consisting of zero or more `'.'`s. It matches the following (quoted) strings:

```
""
"."
".."
"..."
```

*(and so on)*

You want: `"\\..*"` instead. Note that `.` by default does not match line breaks, so it wouldn't match the following string:

```
".Why? \n Not!"
```

For such string to be matched, you need to enable DOT-ALL: `"(?s)\\..*"`

Comment: @Colin, no, the extra backslash is only there because it's placed inside a  string literal in Java. So the string-pattern `"\\."` is equivalent to the regex-pattern: `\.` (note the double quotes!)

Comment: It might be worth explaining that what you mean is that \\.* is true for ".", "..", "...", ... while \\..* is true for ".", ".anything", ".etc",... the \\. being . the second . being anycharacter and the * being repeat that anycharacter rule infinitely.

Comment: @azlisum, the `"\\."` matches the dot at the start of the string, and then `.*` matches the rest of the input (but no line breaks).

Comment: @RobertLouisMurphy, expanded my explanation a bit. Note that `.` does not match *anything* though: it doesn't match line-break chars.

Comment: Now I understand. At the beginning, I thought that "\*" would match any string, but i need ".*" instead. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it myself. This works for me

```
System.out.println(".why?".matches("^\\..*"));
```

You where just missing one "." to match the "why?" part.